# Relation between the 2 interpretations of the Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy (CFL) condition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, error-analysis, stability

In computational fluid dynamics, one tries to ensure that the Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy (CFL) number of the discretization scheme is less than 1. This is done to ensure that the errors made at a certain time step in a certain cell don't grow.

Another conclusion of the CFL condition is that time steps are not larger than the fastest speed in the fluid, i.e., information doesn't travel faster than the time stepping.

What I don't understand is why should these 2 be related? I get that imposing CFL less than 1 mathematically gives the conclusion about the time stepping size and the speed of information passage. However, what I don't understand is why should growth of errors have anything to do with the speed of information transfer. Why should these two be related at all and follow from the same condition?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the dual interpretations is because the [CFL condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition) is an *application* of the numerical analysis procedure called the [von Neumann analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis).

Quoting the linked Wikipedia entry on the von Neumann analysis,

> A finite difference scheme is stable if the errors made at one time step of the calculation do not cause the errors to be magnified as the computations are continued. A neutrally stable scheme is one in which errors remain constant as the computations are carried forward. If the errors decay and eventually damp out, the numerical scheme is said to be stable. If, on the contrary, the errors grow with time the numerical scheme is said to be unstable

Hence, requiring/expecting the amplitude of the error being less than 1 arises from the von Neumann analysis of the scheme. Note that there are schemes in which the error cannot possibly be $\leq1$, in which case they are probably not useful for simulating anything (though I imagine can be useful for practicing stability analysis).

When applying the stability analysis to the [*hyperbolic PDE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation) that we commonly refer to as the [*advection equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection),
$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}$$
which describes a flow moving at a characteristic speed, $u$, do we find the commonly seen,
$$C=u\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}$$
we describe as the CFL condition. Since $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$ represent the grid size and time step & $u$ the wave speed, we get the interpretation that information cannot travel faster than the fastest wavespeed.

Comment: Why should the rate of information travel have anything to do with the growth of errors? Sure, it follows directly from the maths but is there something more physical connecting the two?

Comment: Physics gives physical connection to the mathematics, so it's almost a tautology to say that the physical connection of the two is what the CFL condition states.